# How to find length of char* [] array

Tags: c

```
const char *hey(const char *arr[])
{}
```

If I am given the above function, how would I be able to find the length of the array passed in as parameter? Is it strlen? If it is not, could you please explain to me why you can't use strlen here?

Comment: well, it's an array of pointers. strlen won't work

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre how do you get the length of the array?

Comment: well, that's the catch: you cannot, unless there's a convention with the caller which ends the array with NULL for instance (like execvp does)

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre is there a way to loop through the array?

Comment: With such a declaration you have an **incomplete type**. The C standard allows the use use of array not fully qualified, in that case it is user responsibility to not access memory out of array bounds. In poor words you can't obtain the buffer dimensions...